# Error packaging electron react boilerplate app

Tags: reactjs, electron

I cloned [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) as ebp

Then I packaged it with:

`electron-packager ebp testapp --electron-version=1.7.5`

Then I ran testapp-win32-x64/testapp.exe and I get the following error:

[image]

What's annoying is that I can't see the full trace or copy any of it. Does anybody have any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error messages shown that it is trying to find out some modules but don't get that. Please recheck after clone this project did you install all of the modules correctly or not. To install all of the module try

yarn or npm install

and make sure to check your node version. I highly recommend to follow the documentation from where you clone the project.

[image]

Comment: Yup, I did npm install, and the app works, just not when it's packaged.